# Laravel Responsable - Get Output Attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
class TransformResponse implements Responsable
{
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        $this->name = 'Mr. ' . $this->name;
        return response(['name' => $this->name]);
    }
}
```

-

```
$res = new \TransformResponse('Orocimaru');
return $res; // output { "name": "Mr. Orocimaru" }
return $res->name; // output "Orocimaru"
# expected output "Mr. Orochimaru"
```

-

How to get expected output?

Whether right to do mutation inside toResponse()?

I follow this https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-5-responsable

Comment: Do: `$res = new \TransformResponse('Orocimaru');
$this->name = 'Mr. ' . $res;
        return response(['name' => $this->name]);`

Comment: where to put $this->name = 'Mr. ' . $res;

Comment: In `toResponse` function

Comment: do u mean I should call the class it self inside toResponse? but how to get the $obj->name? toResponse() will not fired. can u answer on answer column please, so I can understand more clearly. Thanks.

Comment: You said this: `$res = new \TransformResponse('Orocimaru');
return $res; // output { "name": "Mr. Orocimaru" }` first let me know is it give you this output { "name": "Mr. Orocimaru" } ?

Comment: yes sir, but toResponse() doen't have $res

Comment: Can you tell me the result of `$request` in `toResponse` function? I mean what you have in `$request`?

Comment: return $request; // output []

Comment: Can you try this plz: `return $res['name']; `

Comment: Cannot use object of type TransformResponse as array

Comment: You can `json_decode($res, true);` Then you can use `return $res['name'];`

Comment: $res = json_decode(json_encode($res), true); return $res['name']; // output "Orochimaru" without "Mr. "